# Starting a Flask Server from Within Test Code?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, flask, functional-testing

I'm working through the Flasky tutorial from Miguel Grinberg's book *Flask Web Development 2e* and I've run into a snag with the end-to-end testing in Chapter 15. When I try to run the code I get a console message

```
* Ignoring a call to 'app.run()' that would block the current 'flask' CLI command.
   Only call 'app.run()' in an 'if __name__ == "__main__"' guard.
```

followed by the browser reporting "Firefox cannot establish a connection..." This suggest to me that the test server is not starting.

Here's the code, from pages 231-233 of the book (the file is `tests/test_selenium.py`):

```py
import threading
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

from app import create_app, db, fake
from app.models import Role, User


class SeleniumTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    browser = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        try:
            cls.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        
        if cls.browser:
            cls.app = create_app('testing')
            cls.app_context = cls.app.app_context()
            cls.app_context.push()

            import logging
            logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
            logger.setLevel('ERROR')

            db.create_all()
            Role.insert_roles()
            fake.users(10)
            fake.posts(10)

            admin_role = Role.query.filter_by(permissions=0xff).first()
            admin = User(email='john@example.com', password='cat', username='john', role=admin_role, confirmed=True)
            db.session.add(admin)
            db.session.commit()

            cls.server_thread = threading.Thread(
                target=cls.app.run,
                kwargs={
                    'debug': 'false',
                    'use_reloader': False,
                    'use_debugger': False,
                    'host': '0.0.0.0',
                    'port': 5000
                }
            )
            cls.server_thread.start()
    
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        if cls.browser:
            cls.browser.get('http://localhost:5000/shutdown')
            cls.browser.quit()
            cls.server_thread.join()

            db.drop_all()
            db.session.remove()

            cls.app_context.pop()
    
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        if not self.browser:
            self.skipTest('Web browser not available')
    
    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        pass

    def test_admin_home_page(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:5000/')   # fails here
        self.assertRegex(self.browser.page_source, 'Hello,\s+Stranger!')

        self.fail('Finish the test!')
```

How can I get a test server up and running from within the test code? (I putzed around with Flask-Testing for a few days before giving it up as unmaintained.)

ADDENDUM: Further experimentation has determined that the problem lies in the explicit call to `app.run()` conflicting with the Flask CLI's *implicit* call to `app.run()`, but without the explicit call the test server doesn't start.

I want to run this from the Flask CLI the same as my unit tests. This means I need to find a way to start the test server *after* the test database is populated, which happens after the test class's code begins to run. The CLI command code is:

```py
@app.cli.command()
@click.argument('test_names', nargs=-1)
def test(coverage, test_names):
    """Run the unit tests"""
    import unittest
    if test_names:
        tests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames(test_names)
    else:
        tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
```

so running from `__main__` would bypass the tests' load/run sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I found a feasible solution using `Timer`

```
import unittest
from threading import Timer
```

Create two variables on top in your code

```
timer = None
myapp = None

class ApplicationTest(unittest.TestCase):
```

Now at the bottom of the file create `main` method and custom method of timer, I assume `startTest` as method name

In the main method you can call `create_app` and put it in global variable and use that `myapp` variable inside your selenium testing code

`unittest.main()` will manually trigger your test class and run the test cases one after one, unfortunately the test runs twice, I don't know why

```
def startTest():
    timer.cancel()
    unittest.main()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer = Timer(6.0, startTest)
    timer.start()
    myapp = create_app()
    myapp.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: That won't work. I need to create the app in testing mode, populate the test database (which is an in-memory Sqlite3 instance), then run the app. See my addendum above for why this needs to happen in `unittest.TestCase.setUpClass()`.

Comment: only inside __main__ you can start the app, it will block the thread